# Sidebar not loading correct place

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a theme oxygen theme  on wordpress but the sidebar is not showing correct you can see its url here

http://212.159.70.57/karen/product-category/women/

You can see the sidebar is showing to the bottom left I have tried changing the main div containers width to fix it but it does not appear to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the container where the products are have a class "row" which gives a 100% width:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="laborator-woocommerce shop">
        <div class="row">...</div>
        <div class="codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper">
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the problem -->
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the problem -->
            <div class="col-md-3 sidebar-env">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One way to fix this is changing the class to one of the classes of your theme, like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="laborator-woocommerce shop">
        <div class="row">...</div>
        <div class="codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper">
            <div class="row">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the change -->
            <div class="col-md-9">...</div>
            <!-- Here is the change -->
            <div class="col-md-3 sidebar-env">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you with the problem.

Comment: yes this does work I just have to figure out how to put it in the theme now as its using wb bakery

Comment: Well, check the templated used by your main theme and the plugin one who does the store catalog @david

Comment: I cannot for the live of me find where this code do you have any ideas in woocmerce where it may be ive tried a search but cannot find it

Comment: Well, how it looks its the plugin theme that is doing that. I will try to check it out in my free time so i search the file who is creating the product list.
If you can comment wich tmeplate are u using and the name of the plugin, that would help me to start with.